# Multiple Users Signing a git Tag or Commit

Tags: git, security, signing, continuous-deployment

My continuous deployment system detects changes to be moved into production only when a git tag is signed by a list of permitted users.

There still remains a risk where one of these users may have there key compromised. To help protect against this, what I would like to explore is the idea of only pushing code changes into production when a git code change is signed by two independent people.

As I understand, both git signing and git tagging only support being signed by one user/key. I'm looking for idea's or suggestions on a good way for how duel signing can be enforced in our continuous-deployment git workflow before code is automatically pushed into production?

Comment: Insanity, pure insanity. Which CDS are you using? Doesn't it allow you to have some kind of acceptance flow?

Comment: You could generate a new key every time and have the key signed by two devs, then sign the commit with that key. When you push, you can check if the key was signed by two developers.

Comment: @creynders, yes we have acceptance tests in the CDS.

Comment: @morxa - sounds interesting, could you elaborate on what the solution of two people signing one key would look like?

Comment: I envisioned the continuous integration system only publishing code changes to an environment IF two people counter sign a code commit. For example, Alice commits some code and signs it. Bob comes along, does a diff to review the changes then counter signs it. It seems that duel signing in this fashion is challenging to achieve and having a duel acceptance process somewhere else in the CI pipelines is the way to go.